# comparison.wordcloud error of strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value (SOLVED)

Tags: r

I have a termdocumentmatrix tdm1 and I put it in through this formula:

comparison.cloud(tdm1, random.order=FALSE,
colors = c("#00B2FF", "red", "#FF0099", "#6600CC", "green", "orange", "blue", "brown"),
title.size=1, max.words=50, scale=c(4, 0.5),rot.per=0.4)

However, I got an error which is "Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value"

Not too sure what cex value am I missing.

The tdm1 is as follows:

```
            Docs
Terms        anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust
  bag            1            0       0    0   0       1        0     0
  choices        1            1       0    0   1       2        1     1
  limited        1            0       0    0   0       1        0     0
  plastic        1            0       0    0   0       1        0     0
  provided       1            0       0    0   0       1        0     0
  abit           0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  ai             0            2       0    0   2       1        2     2
  always         0            1       0    1   0       0        0     1
  amazed         0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  amount         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  app            0            2       0    1   2       1        2     2
  area           0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  areas          0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  around         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  atmosphere     0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  attended       0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  back           0            1       0    0   1       1        1     0
  basah          0            1       0    1   1       0        1     1
  bought         0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  brands         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  bras           0            1       0    1   1       0        1     1
  breeze         0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  buy            0            1       0    1   1       1        1     1
  can            0            2       0    0   1       1        1     0
  cant           0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  cashiers       0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  cbd            0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  charged        0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  choose         0            2       0    0   1       0        0     0
  chopstick      0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  classes        0            1       0    0   1       0        0     0
  come           0            2       0    0   2       2        2     1
  concept        0            4       0    0   3       0        3     3
  confused       0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  contains       0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  convenient     0            8       0    0   5       1        4     4
  cool           0            4       0    0   4       1        4     4
  correct        0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  cream          0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  cup            0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  curious        0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  current        0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  customer       0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  cutlery        0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  doesnt         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  dont           0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  don’t          0            1       0    1   1       1        1     1
  download       0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  drinks         0            1       0    0   1       0        0     0
  easy           0            3       0    0   2       0        2     2
  eat            0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  electronic     0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  eleven         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  entering       0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  ereciept       0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  especially     0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  even           0            2       0    2   1       1        1     1
  exit           0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  experience     0            3       0    1   2       1        2     2
  explained      0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  feel           0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  first          0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  found          0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  free           0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  friends        0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  fussfree       0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  gantry         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  get            0            2       0    1   2       1        1     1
  go             0            3       0    1   3       1        3     3
  good           0            2       0    0   2       0        2     2
  goods          0            1       0    1   1       1        1     1
  goto           0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  great          0            4       0    0   3       0        3     3
  greatly        0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  hasslefree     0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  history        0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  hope           0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  hour           0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  hours          0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  ice            0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  im             0            1       0    0   1       1        1     0
  inside         0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  items          0            3       0    0   3       2        3     2
  jiffy          0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  just           0            4       0    0   3       2        3     2
  large          0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  leave          0            1       0    0   1       1        1     0
  less           0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  link           0            2       0    0   2       1        2     2
  linked         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  lots           0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  love           0            3       0    0   3       1        3     2
  lovely         0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  makes          0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  making         0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  many           0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  method         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  methods        0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  minute         0            2       0    0   1       1        1     2
  mrt            0            1       0    1   1       0        1     1
  muchneeded     0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  near           0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  nearby         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  new            0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  newly          0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  nice           0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  noodles        0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  number         0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  offers         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  often          0            2       0    0   2       2        2     1
  opened         0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  operate        0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  order          0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  outlets        0            1       0    0   1       1        1     0
  patiently      0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  pay            0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  payment        0            3       0    0   3       1        3     3
  people         0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  perfect        0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  pick           0            4       0    0   3       0        3     3
  picking        0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  prepare        0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  prices         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  product        0            2       0    0   2       2        2     2
  products       0            7       0    0   5       1        5     4
  promotion      0            1       0    1   1       0        1     1
  promotions     0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  quench         0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  queue          0            2       0    0   2       1        2     2
  quite          0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  range          0            2       0    0   1       1        1     0
  ready          0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  reasonable     0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  recieved       0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  recommend      0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  reduced        0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  rush           0            1       0    0   1       1        1     0
  salut          0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  sandwiches     0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  scan           0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  see            0            3       0    0   2       0        2     2
  seems          0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  setup          0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  shop           0            3       0    0   2       1        2     2
  shopping       0            4       0    1   4       2        4     4
  show           0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  small          0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  smu            0            2       0    0   2       0        2     2
  snacks         0            3       0    0   3       1        1     1
  spent          0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  staff          0            3       0    1   3       3        3     3
  stared         0            1       0    1   1       1        1     1
  stop           0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  store          0           14       0    0  10       5        9     9
  stores         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  students       0            1       0    0   1       0        0     0
  stuff          0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  super          0            2       0    0   2       0        2     2
  sure           0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  sweets         0            1       0    0   1       0        0     0
  take           0            1       0    0   1       1        1     0
  technology     0            4       0    0   4       2        4     4
  thankfully     0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  theres         0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  thirst         0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  thought        0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  time           0            2       0    0   2       1        2     2
  took           0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  truly          0            1       0    0   0       0        0     1
  unmanned       0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  use            0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  used           0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  useful         0            1       0    0   1       0        0     0
  users          0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  variety        0            4       0    0   4       0        3     3
  wait           0            2       0    0   1       0        1     1
  waited         0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  walk           0            2       0    0   1       0        1     1
  want           0            1       0    0   0       0        0     0
  wanted         0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  wasnt          0            1       0    0   1       1        1     1
  whatever       0            1       0    0   1       0        1     1
  wide           0            4       0    0   3       1        2     1
  won’t          0            1       0    1   1       1        1     1
  worry          0            1       0    1   1       1        1     1
  avoid          0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  away           0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  better         0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  choice         0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  customers      0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  deceptive      0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  expired        0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  listed         0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  make           0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  marketing      0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  minutes        0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  much           0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  purchases      0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  qr             0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  resulting      0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  scanner        0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  screen         0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  showing        0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  still          0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  takes          0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  tries          0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  trusted        0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  trusting       0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
  works          0            0       0    1   0       0        0     0
```

Hence, not too sure what is the issue about since there is no NA!

Hope you can help. Thank you!

Comment: Hard to test without data or much code, but your "disgust" column is all zeros?

Comment: Hi @Isaiah, I managed to solve the error thanks to your help. After removing the disgust column, I managed to run it without any error.

Comment: To those who faced similar issue as this next time, make sure your termdocumentmatrix does not have any weird characters, empty space on the leftmost column and also sentiments without any being filled. This would result in the comparison wordcloud to be confused about cex since there is a sentiment without any words tagged to it